Getting Error whikle using temp table along with CTE in SSIS DFT
I have one SQL query which I want to use in SSIS package. In that query I have one temp table used along with CTE. Whenever I am trying to use it I am getting error. Could anyone please help here.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tempdb') is not null
drop table ##tempdb

select * into ##tempdb from Account_Master

;with cte
as
(
    select Beneficiary_ID, Account_Number, Account_ID
    from Beneficiary_Master
)
select beneficiary_id, account_number, Account_Type
from cte a
inner join ##tempdb b
    on a.account_id = b.Account_ID

Error I am getting :

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB
Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement
'with cte as ( select Beneficiary_ID, Account_Number, Account_ID  from
Beneficiary_Master )select' uses a temp table.  Metadata discovery
only supports temp tables when analyzing a single-statement batch.".
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: Unable to retrieve column
information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
database is available.


It is trying to validate the table/query and it fails because the temp table does not exist at the time.  The setting to stop it from validating before it executes (if I remember is) to right click on the task, go to properties, and select:  Delay Validation and set to True.
This will delay the validation/meta data scan and should let you run the package.

Thanks @Brad. But I already made the necessay chnages in the package. Even after delaying the metadata validation it is giving same error.

Are you using the temp table in any other object/box in SSIS than the one you created?  So you insert into temp table in one SQL script task, but are you using it in any other script tasks or just contained in the one?  If you are trying to use the temp table in multiple script tasks/SSIS tasks, you may have to select the option in properties to retain same connection for those multiple SQL script tasks.

No. I am only using it in source side of the package. Just for testing purpose I bring the OLEDB source in the DFT and use the SQL command option to pick the query and then trying to execute it.

This question is similar to: SSIS Package not wanting to fetch metadata of temporary table. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why, out of interest, use a temporary table here at all (and more especially why a "global" temporary table)?

Also, as side note, SQLNCLI was discontinued back in 2014; you really should have started using MSOLEDBSQL by now.
